Can we incorporate some building block colors somewhere in the LEGO Answers banner?
Is there some way we can get StackExchange to incorporate some classic LEGO colors somewhere in the LEGO Answers.SE page banners? Some old school yellow, green, red and/or blue would fit in nicely.

Really we should have some more traction on Can I suggest a more LEGO-y skin ;) Perhaps we can get Jin to take a look and make us a little more welcoming.

Nice. I'd say the skin post makes my question a duplicate. I voted the other question up +1.
